# Following references through multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following (for this example simplified) SQL table structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE clients (
            id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
            datetime timestamp DEFAULT now(),
            alias VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL);
   CREATE TABLE B1 (
            id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
            datetime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
            client uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES clients (id));
   CREATE TABLE B2 (
            id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
            datetime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
            sender uuid REFERENCES B1 (id),
            receiver uuid REFERENCES B1 (id));
```

Given a row of table `B2`, what is the most efficient way of retrieving the `alias` fields corresponding to `sender` and  `receiver`? I have a quite complex query consisting of 4 nested `inner join` operations that does the job, but I feel this is a fairly standard operation and there must be a better way (in other languages this would simply be `sender.client.alias`).

Here's what I have to extract the two `client` IDs, which involves only one level of references and already looks inefficient:

```
SELECT u1.client, u2.client
FROM B2 
INNER JOIN B1 as u1 on u1.id = B2.sender
INNER JOIN B1 as u2 on u2.id = B2.receiver
```

In practice all three tables have millions of rows and the request is time-sensitive (<1ms).

Comment: You want *all* related senders and receivers in less than a millisecond? Good luck.

Comment: Not all of them, but likely on the order of 1000-2000. The full set gets reduced with a time-based ‘where’ statement returning only recent ones.

Comment: did you consider caching or creating views or creating procedures or using indexes? Maybe storing the needed information in a separate table? What did you try so far and what was the outcome?

Comment: do you have indexes on sender, receiver and client ?

Comment: You need to show the *exact* statement that should be fast, plus `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.